# MYSQL left join on multiple fields

Tags: mysql, join

I have a friends table.  Is it possible to do a left join on two fields of the table.  In other words, I don't know which of the two fields may have the match I need.  If not is there another way to do this?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `friends` f
LEFT JOIN `users` u
ON f.askee OR f.asker = u.ID
where (asker='$userid' OR askee='$userid') AND status='3'";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left join is correct: the OR operator will do what you expect. But then your filter on `$userid` should apply to the parent table (`friends`), not left joined one (otherwise it would cancel the outer join):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `friends` f
LEFT JOIN `users` u ON f.`askee` = u.`ID` OR f.`asker` = u.`ID`
WHERE u.`status` = '3' AND u.ID = '$userid'";
```

Comment: This could also end up with combinations where f.asker=$userid and f.askee=u.ID, f.askee=$userid and f.asker=u.ID, f.asker=$userid and f.asker=u.ID, f.askee=$userid and f.askee=u.ID. It's hard to say if those are all valid results for what the op wants.

Comment: correct, that's why we need the functional background to give a better answer. As for the technical point this is ok I think.

Comment: edited: what I really want is if the match in the where is on asker, to get the info on askee from users while if the match in the where is on askee to get the info on asker from users..asker and askee will always be different

Comment: Please check the edited version. Now it is really either or, and there has to be a user for asker or askee.

Comment: Not sure u.ID = '$userid' in INNER JOIN is correct as $userid is for the user..and we want to pull the friend's U.ID as key to friend's data.  Basically, we want to pull friend data here.  Start by finding friend in friends table using userid of user which can be in either asker or askee, as user could have initiated or responded to friend request.  Get userid of friend.  then use that as key to get friend's info.  Maybe there is a better way to do friends table.

Comment: "$userid is for the user", maybe, but you're doing exactly the same doing this: f.askee OR f.asker = u.ID: you compare a userid to a friend.

Comment: by setting u.id <> userid in new version, I was able to get the other party of the friendship (not user) which is what I want.  But now getting double records of same friend.

Comment: Got it.  Used original query and u.id <>$userid.  Many thanks.